# Ruby on Rails Unwanted Object Caching Behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class, caching, activerecord

I'm trying to run a simple loop that increments an attribute in a database table, and isn't incrementing as expected. Imagine that our application is a daily deals site. I'm using Rails 3.0.1, for the record.

```
class Deal
  has_many :orders
end

class Order
  belongs_to :deal
end
```

An Order also has an attribute "quantity" - for example of someone buys a few of the same thing.
if someone buys a bunch of orders in a shopping cart, we want to tally the total in each deal to track how many we sold in each deal.

```
@new_orders.each do |order|
  order.deal.update_attribute(:order_count, order.deal.order_count + order.quantity)
end
```

Firstly, ignore the fact that there may be a better way to write this. This is a contrived example in order to get to my point.

Now, imagine that our current case is where someone bought 3 orders of the same deal in the shopping cart (for no good reason - this example is somewhat contrived). And let's say each order had a quantity of 1.

I would have expected, at the end of the loop, the deal's quantity to be 3. But when I run this code, whether in tests, on the browser, or in the console, I get 1.

It seems as if in each iteration of the loop, when it pulls "order.deal" - since each order happens to belong to the same deal, it's pulling the deal from a cache. So let's say before this loop began, the deal's order_count was 0, each time it pulls a cached copy of the deal which has an order_count of 0.

Is this the expected behavior? Is there a way to turn off this type of caching? What's even stranger is that a colleague of mine tried to run a similar loop in his project and got the expected total. Or am I missing something entirely?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't saving the record.  After the increment (but within the loop), you need:

```
order.deal.save
```

~~~~~~

Based on your comment:

```
@new_orders.each do |order|
  order_quantity = order.quantity
  order.reload
  order.deal.update_attribute(:order_count, order.deal.order_count + order_quantity)
end
```

This will save the new order quantity in a variable, reload the order from the database and then do the update.

Comment: Thanks for your response; I've edited the code above to where it saves (using update_attribute) but I still get the same problem.

Comment: Thanks so much - that worked! Can you explain why the order has to be reloaded? I didn't modify it at all before the reload.

Comment: If you iterate through the same order multiple times, then you have changed the order each time you iterated through it (you increased the order count).  Rails has already loaded the orders when you do the each, so even if you have increased it earlier, when you get to it next time, it contains the old value, and then just adds to that and saves it.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense in general. But here, I'm not iterating through the same order multiple times. @new_orders.each is referring to several different orders. And even if all the orders are loaded as the loop begins, here I'm updating the 'deal' (order.deal) that the order belongs to.